# Converting basic program into a function for random inputs

Tags: java, arrays, string, function

This below program written only to convert "hello word" so I want it as a **universal function that takes any kind of letter or word and return the answer in an integer array.**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class JavaApplication1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Map<Character, Integer> map;
        final String str = "hello word";

        map = new HashMap<>();  
        map.put('a', 1);
        map.put('i', 1);
        map.put('j', 1);
        map.put('q', 1);
        map.put('y', 1);

        map.put('b', 2);
        map.put('k', 2);
        map.put('r', 2);

        map.put('c', 3);
        map.put('g', 3);
        map.put('l', 3);
        map.put('s', 3);

        map.put('d', 4);
        map.put('m', 4);
        map.put('t', 4);

        map.put('e', 5);
        map.put('h', 5);
        map.put('n', 5);
        map.put('x', 5);

        map.put('u', 6);
        map.put('v', 6);
        map.put('w', 6);

        map.put('o', 7);
        map.put('z', 6);

        map.put('f', 8);
        map.put('p', 8);

        System.out.println("output:");

        for(final char c : str.toCharArray())
        {
            final Integer val;

            val = map.get(c);

            if(val == null)
            {   
                // some sort of error
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(val + " ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output for above code:**

5 5 3 3 7 6 7 2 4

my question is how to convert the above code to public function like this...

public static String str(String newstr) 
{

...........

..........

.........

return array;  //integer array containing value

}

**if i call the function by sending a string as input into it. it should return integer array as answer.**

**Detail explanation about the program:-**

This program takes input string (letter, word etc..) and converts all the letters into numerical value that has been assigned for each alphabet and stores in an array

Each alphabet having a numerical value shown below:-

1 = A I J Q Y

2 = B K R

3 = C G L S

4 = D M T

5 = E H N X

6 = U V W

7 = O Z

8 = F P

Comment: So you are basically asking for finished code, working solution, not even asking particular question?

Comment: three hints: 1) function's return type should be the array's type;  2) you have to create an array of the same length as your string;  3) instead of writing each number to `System.out` you need to assign it to a cell of the array

Comment: @Eel Lee
how to convert the code into a function tht returns array..
iam new to java i found it difficult to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With little modifications to your code you are good to go:

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Q1_JavaApplication1 {

```
/**
 * Constructor
 * @param stringToMap
 */
public Q1_JavaApplication1(String stringToMap){

    mapStringToNumbers(stringToMap);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param stringToMap
 */
private int[] mapStringToNumbers(String stringToMap) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map;
    String str = stringToMap;
    str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");//remove empty strings
    char[]ca = str.trim().toCharArray();//initiate char array
    int[] intArray = new int[ca.length];//initiate integer array

    map = new HashMap<>();  
    map.put('a', 1);
    map.put('i', 1);
    map.put('j', 1);
    map.put('q', 1);
    map.put('y', 1);

    map.put('b', 2);
    map.put('k', 2);
    map.put('r', 2);

    map.put('c', 3);
    map.put('g', 3);
    map.put('l', 3);
    map.put('s', 3);

    map.put('d', 4);
    map.put('m', 4);
    map.put('t', 4);

    map.put('e', 5);
    map.put('h', 5);
    map.put('n', 5);
    map.put('x', 5);

    map.put('u', 6);
    map.put('v', 6);
    map.put('w', 6);

    map.put('o', 7);
    map.put('z', 6);

    map.put('f', 8);
    map.put('p', 8);

    System.out.println("output:");

    for(int i = 0; i < ca.length; i ++){//populate and print integer array content
        intArray[i] = map.get(ca[i]);
        System.out.print(intArray[i] + " ");
    }
    return intArray;// return your array
}

/**
 * 
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringToMap = "good morning";//Get your input from args[] OR from keyboard/system.in - for example Scanner OR hard code in main() method (like here)..
    new Q1_JavaApplication1(stringToMap);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create a function with desired signature below is a sample:

```
public static int[] convert(String str) {
     int[] returnVal = new int[str.length];
     int i =0;
      // put here your logic of map population and while loop

     // replace System.out.print(val + " "); 
      returnVal[i++]=val;
     // remaining code
    return returnVal;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: return variable must be an array.. how to return a array which contains output answer

Comment: bro iam weak in java... pls i am struggling from 2 days..
this s the exact function iam looking for...
pls give me a full code..

Answer (score 0):

Some notes:

- I wouldn't return an int array, but a vector.
- If you are really only having 8 values if statements are probably faster

This is untested code:

```
public class Converter {
    private static final Map<Character, Integer> VAL_MAP;
    static {
        VAL_MAP = new HashMap<>(26);
        // put all values into map
        // Collections.unmodifiableMap might be interesting here
    }

    public static int[] convert(String str) {
      // check if str is null... or add @NonNull

      // first count characters we can convert:
      int counter = 0;
      for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (VAL_MAP.containsKey(c)) counter++;
      }

      int[] result = new int[counter];
      int runner = 0;
      for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (VAL_MAP.containsKey(c)) result[runner++] = VAL_MAP.get(c); 
      }
      return result;
    }
}
```